# UnboundLocalError from imported class

Tags: python, global

I have some code that is structured as follows

```
from my.modules import MyClass

Class AnotherClass(object):

  def __init__(a): #line 5
    if a:
      setup_a()
    else:
      setup_b()

  def setup_a():
    # Do some stuff to get local_x
    # ..
    self.a = MyClass(local_x)

  def setup_b():
    # Do some stuff to get local_y
    # ..
    self.b = MyClass(local_y)
```

However I run with `a = True` in line 5 it runs fine, but when I run with `a = False` I get an `UnboundedLocalError`. I understand what causes this normally (modifying a global variable) and if I change setup_b() to:

```
def setup_b():
        global MyClass
        # Do some stuff to get local_y
        # ..
        self.b = MyClass(local_y)
```

It works correctly. I just don't understand why I am getting this error as I am not modifying the MyClass by instantiating it.

Note: The above example is a basic version of the code not the actual code producing the error.
Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in the code you're not showing you're assigning to `MyClass`, making the compiler think that it's a local variable when it's not.

Comment: Yep that was it. We had a series of imports under `self.b = MyClass(local_y)` one of which was incorrectly importing MyClass